# Make div top position change every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have an absolutely positioned div with children. I want this divs top position to change every x seconds. I have tried with jquery `setInterval` but it only changes once. Below is my code.

```
.com_prices {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #dd0d0d;
  position: relative;
} 
.com_tabs {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.com_price_tab {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff; 
}
```

The html

```
<div class="com_prices">
    <div class="com_tabs">
      <div class="com_price_tab"></div>
      <div style="background: #28bc88" class="com_price_tab"></div>
      <div style="background: #fff000" class="com_price_tab"></div>
      <div style="background: #333" class="com_price_tab"></div>
      <div style="background: #28bc88" class="com_price_tab"></div>
      <div style="background: #999" class="com_price_tab"></div>
      <div class="com_price_tab"></div>
      <div class="com_price_tab"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The script

```
 setInterval(function() {
    $('.com_tabs').animate({top: "-100px"}, 350);
 }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the `top` position to -100px. After the first time the function is trying to set the top position to be the same value it's already at (-100px) and thus not making any change.
You could get the current top value and subtract 100px from the value. Something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var $el = $('.com_tabs');
    var top = $el.css('top');
        var topNumber = top.substr(0, top.length -2) - 100;
        console.log(topNumber);
        $el.animate({top: topNumber + 'px'}, 350);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting top equal to "-100px". You need to get the current position subtract 100.

```
 var $comtabs = $('.com_tabs');
 setInterval(function() {
    var top = parseInt($comtabs.css("top"));
    $comtabs.animate({top: top - 100 + "px"}, 350);
 }, 2000);
```

Working example:

```js
var $comtabs = $('.com_tabs');
setInterval(function() {
  var top = parseInt($comtabs.css("top"));
  $comtabs.animate({
    top: top - 100 + "px"
  }, 350);
}, 2000);
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.com_prices {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #dd0d0d;
  position: relative;
}

.com_tabs {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.com_price_tab {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="com_prices">
  <div class="com_tabs">
    <div class="com_price_tab"></div>
    <div style="background: #28bc88" class="com_price_tab"></div>
    <div style="background: #fff000" class="com_price_tab"></div>
    <div style="background: #333" class="com_price_tab"></div>
    <div style="background: #28bc88" class="com_price_tab"></div>
    <div style="background: #999" class="com_price_tab"></div>
    <div class="com_price_tab"></div>
    <div class="com_price_tab"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here you go with the updated version https://jsfiddle.net/z8gf334f/1/ . Once it reaches bottom it will roll back to top.

Comment: @Shiladitya That would be a separate question. If you want to accept this answer then post the question about how to roll back in a new post, you can link it in the comments here and I will attempt to answer that as well.